# How do I repair my lawn mower wheel drive that doesn't stop?

Tags: lawn-mower

I have Craftsman 917.388740 self-propelled mower. The original drive belt stretched & no longer had enough tension, even with adjustments, to move the wheels. Unfortunately, Sears online & phone parts, as well as other online parts stores, no longer show the drive mechanism on their parts diagrams or list a belt (I triple checked model number), so I didn't know what size belt to get.

I took the old belt to a shop & they sold me new belt that's a little shorter which I installed & adjusted using the knob on the drive lever. Now it takes off at high speed with lever in off position.

- I removed corrosion & polished the inner surface of drive pulley.
- I took the lever mechanism apart to make sure cable travels the full amount & lubricated cable which slides easily.

Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Does anybody know correct belt size for this model or have other recommendations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a home improvement related question

Comment: It sounds to me like you've still got too much tension on the belt. If you've adjusted the drive system to its maximum travel and the belt is still too tight, you may need a longer belt. It's also possible that, even though the cable is moving, the clutch that it's supposed to control is stuck, or that the cable came off the clutch mechanism while you were fiddling with other things.

Comment: WTH?  You don’t adjust the belt tension with the drive lever!  The drive lever is telling the transmission which ratio to use.  It’s going forward because it thinks you are commanding that, because you messed with the drive lever linkage.  Unmess it.  Then adjust drive belt tension in the place you do that, which is not anywhere near the transmission.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/430587/Craftsman-917.html?page=20#manual) seems to indicate that the belt tension isn't adjustable. Can you clarify what you adjusted?

Comment: @Harper I think you may be confused. This is a walk behind mower and perhaps you're thinking a tractor or ride more.

Comment: @isherwood There is a small knob on the traction control lever mechanism with instructions to pull out with lever in off position, then push back in. It self adjusts,  but only a small amount. I took the belt back to the mower shop and got a liner once,  but haven't had a chance yet to install it. I had another thought. The worn belt and the one they sold me first were only about 3/8" wide & ride deep in the pulleys.  Maybe there belt is sho old the sides wore down & are binding in there pulleys. I got a wider longer belt to try. Thanks for answering. Will update.

Comment: @freeman I doesn't have a clutch. This is an old machine. There bitterly just slips when tension is released. Also, you may be thinking tractor, while mine is walk behind. Thanks

Comment: @harper Also, your tone seems a little harsh for a first answer. If I were being an idiot I would accept your dismissive tone.  But in the future, perhaps you should allow that you might not always understand the problem exactly. But thank you for answering.

Comment: @ack I have not posted for a while, so I'm not sure I know all the rules. But I think you will find many posts about maintaining lawn mowers and other equipment used in home improvement in a broad sense. I could not find a category on lawn mower repair,  but if you are aware of a once that is more appropriate,  please let me know. That might be more constructive. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @FreeMan I think the problem is the reverse of what you you are imagining. The belt does not slip as it is supp when the tension cable is released.

Comment: Um, yeah, I knew that... I think I got cornfused there...

Comment: I got stuck initially because I assumed incorrectly that the mower shop knew the right belt. I'm experimenting with different belts now and will comment when I find one that works. Thanks so much.

Comment: The problem is resolved. It seems it was not a worn belt after all. In the process of trying different sized belts, I lubricated the tensioner cable and cleaned the cobwebs and dust in the tension control mechanism. The belts were all too short or too long. Finally, I reinstalled the old cable and it now works. Lesson learned: If after some years the belt no longer tightens enough, don't jump to the conclusion that there's a problem with the belt. Unless the belt is seriously worn, I believe the problem is more likely in the cable and tensioner mechanism. Thank you all.